# Why Kentico form creates a long query string on submit

Tags: kentico

I have prepared a custom form in Kentico and it has around 15 fields. when I submit the form it creates a long query string which results an error -

**The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.**

Am I doing something wrong while setting the form?

Comment: Do you have a nested form somewhere on your page?  I have several sites with more than 25 or 30 fields which work without issue.

Comment: Its just one form on the page. Also, is it important to create an alternative form?

Comment: What does your "After the form is submitted" setting in Kentico look like - do you possibly have a query string set in the "Redirect to URL" field? Can you give an example of the long query string?

Comment: Here is the Query String -

Comment: https://codepen.io/kunal-chawla/pen/ZqjJyp Please check the link for the URL. I have added that in the HTML section.

Comment: Also, I have selected "Clear form" option for after the form is submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to updated everyone. The HTML on the master page contain another  tag for search box, which is typical for designers to do not knowing .NET doesn't like other  tags. And KC added another  tag wrapping the biz-form layout which led to the postback error. Once those  tags are removed, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When getting the query string is too long error it usually means that the query string exceeded its maximum query-string size, You could try increase the maximum query-string size by setting the maxQueryString attribute in the request filtering section in your web.config.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="9096648" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: The issue is not related to this. I have already set the value in web.config to 2147483648. The issue is something in Kentico settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [request filtering module](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/modules/kentico-request-filtering-module) from market place by any chance? Try to disable it or uninstall to see if it changes the situation. It must be some  settings in there or a rule.

Comment: No, I can't find anything like that in the Kentico.